# How get last fgetcsv call to csv file?

Tags: php, csv, time

Scructure:

- project/index.php
- project/index.csv

index.php

```
<?php
$file = 'index.csv';
$array = file_get_contents($file);
echo $ctime = filectime($file) . PHP_EOL;
echo $atime = fileatime($file) . PHP_EOL;
echo $mtime = filemtime($file);
```

returns

```
1561541778
1561541779
1561541778
```

if file doesn't change, return param don't change

if file open, return param don't change

if file edit, return param change

but I want to get time of last call `file_get_contents()` to this file.

Comment: you can simply store the time you make the call since it is your code